"Where did you get THIS done?" VS "Where did you get IT done?"
On TV, the presenters and the guests are talking about some aesthetics surgery, which later on caused serious problems. A woman is telling about what she has gone through. So, the following is a small part from their talk:
TV presenter: Where did you get THIS done?
The guest: So, I had THIS done in the London area.
I noticed both speakers used "THIS", which obviously refers to the surgery. However, as a non-native speaker it wouldn't even occur to me to use "THIS".
I thought we must use "it", because the subject of the talk has already been mentioned at the very beginning, and they have actually been talking about it for a while. But interestingly they both say "this". Maybe it is a concidence, maybe not.
So, I wonder is there a particular reason to do so, or is it simply a preference. In other words, if I had used "it" instead of "this", would it have been wrong?

This or it can be used here. I don't understand why you even asked this. I don't understand why you asked it.

@Lambie, I asked because I would not imagine using "this" as a non-native speaker. At school, we were taught that we should use "it" if a subject is already known to both speakers. And when I saw both speakers used "this", I thought it couldnt have been been a coicidence, and that there might be a reason for their using "this". When you are non-native speaker, you can never be sure 100 % and you always want to verify when two native speakers's speech is contrary to what you were taught at school. So I wanted to make sure what I know to be correct so far wasn't wrong.

"it" is a tad more reductive than "this".

The presenter and the lady were discussing a subject. This and that can always be used in situations like that.

This question is similar to: Get or Have Something Done with Past Participle Verb (Participle Adjective or Passive Voice). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Chenmunka, The question is not about causative. It has nothing to do with get. It is about the difference between pronouns "IT" and "THIS". Did you really read the question especially the last sentence?

@Chenmunka Hope you review carefully next time, not only for close votes, but also suggested edits.

Both “This” and “It” can be used in this context, and I don’t think there’s any big differences between these two words in this context.
Both of them can be used to refer to previously-mentioned problems.
Like what @Michael Harvey said, “this” can also be something that is obvious.

"I don't there's any big differences". Yep, I can see why.

Please change "Is" to "It", as well as addressing the problem mentioned by Lambi and Mari-Lou-A

'This' can be something that is obvious.

@Karen, Lambie I have already edited the post.
