Should i use "that" or " it"?
I have a lot of experience as a chef!
In the united states?
No, that/it was in my home country.
Which one is better?

Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/357622/172656

I find that you ask many questions about grammar, but lacks of research. For this question, did you search “it vs that” on Google?

Source, please. This sounds like it could come from the TV series Bear. Am I right? But if you created these sentence, please say so IN the question.

Don't forget to upvote those answer(s) that helped you the most. Click on the arrow pointing up.

“That” is preferred in two situations:

When the object being referred to is some distance away from the speaker (not relevant in your case)
When the object being referred to is one of two possibilities

“I have a lot of experience as a chef.”
“In the United States?”
“No, that was in my home country. In the US, I worked as a  waiter.”
The two possibilities are often “that” and “this”, “that” being the one more remote in time and space.
Sidenote: in English, the name of any specific place is capitalized.  “China” is a country; ”china” is ceramic tableware.  “Polish” is the language of Poland; “polish” means to make metal shine.
